# Print all the data from table1 and matching data from table 2 but what if the table2 is null

Tags: sql

As I am trying to learn SQL, I have came across this question.

Let's say I have two tables:
**table1** which contains two columns
**id** and **data1**
and
**table2** which also has two columns
**p_id** and **data2**.

How would I print out all the data from **table1** and just matching data from **table2** in two different scenarios.
Scenario 1: table1.id = 1
Scenario 2: what if the **table2** is null, (but I still want to print out all the data from table1)

So my approach was
Scenario 1:

```
Select table1.id, table1.data1, table2.data2
From table1 
Inner Join table2 On table1.id=table2.p_id
Where table1.id = 1;
```

Scenario 2:

```
Select table1.id, table1.data1, table2.data2
From table1 
Inner Join table2 On table1.id=table2.p_id
Where table1.id = 1 and table2.data2 is not null;
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN but that would always print all from table1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second scenario, you are describing a `left join`:

```
Select table1.id, table1.data1, table2.data2
From table1 left Join
     table2
     On table1.id = table2.p_id  
where table1.id = 1 ;
```

Because you are filtering on the *first* table, the condition remains in the `where` clause.  If you wanted to filter on the second table, you would presumably want something like:

```
Select table1.id, table1.data1, table2.data2
From table1 left Join
     table2
     On table1.id = table2.p_id and
        table2.col = 'xyz';
```